# Using Chef Server, what is a good pattern for removing duplicate calls to a particular resource?

Tags: chef

I have a recipe with multiple calls to a given resource, let's say `directory`. The calls to `directory`, for the most part, have very similar parameters (i.e. same owner, same action, etc.) - i.e. a lot of duplication. However, there is a particular parameter that changes frequently, namely the mode.

My goal is to reduce the duplication in my recipes and create something of a convenience method.

I'm leaning towards creating a library with a method like this:

```
def apply_directory_rule(path, mode_num)
  directory path do
    owner "something"
    group "something_else"
    mode mode_num
    action :create
  end
end
```

Then, in the recipe, each time I wanted to create a directory for the applications, I would simply call the following:

```
applications.each do |application|
  apply_directory_rule "#{application}/shared", 0755
end
```

I have not been able to test this yet, but I guess my main question is whether or not Resources, in this case `directory` are available like this in libraries? Secondarily, I'm not convinced this is the best pattern - any suggestions to reduce this duplication in my recipes is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply define a method in a recipe, and use it in that recipe. It's simple and gets the job done.

If you need to reuse the pattern in different recipes, or just want to use more "Chef-y" approach, there are two tools specifically for this.

In simple cases, you can use [definitions](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_definitions.html); more complex situations require writing your own [lightweight resource and provider (LWRP)](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_lwrp.html). Both are usable in other recipes and in other cookbooks.

You can read a good writeup on creating LWRPs here: 
http://dougireton.com/blog/2012/12/31/creating-an-lwrp/,
http://dougireton.com/blog/2013/01/07/creating-an-lwrp-part-2/,
http://dougireton.com/blog/2013/01/13/creating-an-lwrp-part-3/.